# Prefix getting repeated in connect-redis

Tags: node.js, redis

I am trying to use connect-redis: "~3.0.1" with  express-session: "~1.12.1" in my web app to store user sessions. But when I give the prefix field in RedisStore, its getting repeated two times. Please tell if I am doing something wrong.

"mySession:mySession:yzO1mRhloENUMYLkAz2nZprcfvcFMNHY"
   "mySession:mySession:0L8prCJAoq0CmJ9tTwTJ_smQ4fH2R_H9"

While searching I came across similar issue with laravel code:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5353

Please tell if something similar is happening here and if yes, what is the workaround.

Below is the code I am using:

```
var sessionMiddleware = session({
 secret : 'secretPass',
 store: new RedisStore({
   prefix:'mySession:',
   ttl: 1800}),
 resave: false,
 saveUninitialized: false
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var tries = 3;

  function lookupSession(error) {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    }

   tries -= 1

   if (req.session !== undefined) {
     return next();
   }

   if (tries < 0) {
     var errorMsg = 'Error in getting session. Please refresh the page.';
     return next(new Error(errorMsg));      
   }

   sessionMiddleware(req, res, lookupSession);
 }

 lookupSession();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by creating redis client before hand and passing it to the session object as mentioned below and not depend on connect-redis to create it for me.

```
redis_client = require('redis').createClient();

var sessionMiddleware = session({
  secret : 'secretPass',
  store: new RedisStore({
    prefix:'mySession:',
    ttl: 1800,
    client: redis_client}),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
```

});

If i dont pass the client, the below code in connect-redis.js is passing the options while creating the redis client and then is adding one extra prefix.

```
// convert to redis connect params
if (options.client) {
  this.client = options.client;
}
else if (options.socket) {
  this.client = redis.createClient(options.socket, options);
}
else {
   this.client = redis.createClient(options);
}
```

Comment: Fixed in release 3.0.2 in connect-redis